Стрелка слайдера не работает на предпоследнем слайде
Использую слайдер Swiper, всё вроде бы работает, но когда листаешь слайдер с помощью стрелок, то стрелка активна, пока не дойдет до предпоследнего слайда, а дальше не хочет. При этом если свайпать, то свайпает без проблем. Проблема на разрешении экрана - 1027px.
конфиг такой:


const beforeafter = document.querySelector("#service-beforeafter");
if (beforeafter) {
  const slider = new Swiper(beforeafter, {
    autoHeight: false,

    breakpoints: {
      0: {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 18,
        loop: true,
        navigation: false,
        // touchStartPreventDefault: true,
        effect: 'creative',
        creativeEffect: {
          prev: {
            translate: [-316, 0, 0],
          },
          next: {
            translate: [316, 0, 0],
          },
        },
      },
      501: {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 28,
        enabled: true,
        // touchStartPreventDefault: true,
        effect: 'creative',
        creativeEffect: {
          prev: {
            translate: [-760, 0, 0],
          },
          next: {
            translate: [760, 0, 0],
          },
        },
      },

      1025: {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 60,
        noSwipingClass: 'handle',
        effect: 'creative',
        creativeEffect: {
          prev: {
            translate: [-792, 0, 0],
          },
          next: {
            translate: [792, 0, 0],
          },
        },
      },
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

  });
}



Последний слайдер не выводится кликом на стрелку.
Ошибок в консоли нет.

